# Markdown table in Jupyter notebook not working

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

I know how to set to up a table in a jupyter notebook`. I even looked up internet and imitated it. However it is not working? Anyone can tell me what is wrong with my notebook, is there anything I should change while constructing markdown table

```
 Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

- the example code is missing the first `|` character
- dollar signs need to be escaped with a backslash (`\`) since MathJax is enabled

Try this:

```
|Tables         | Are           | Cool   |
| ------------- |:-------------:| ------:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | \$1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   \$12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    \$1 |
```